# End play event for Audio class?

Tags: javascript

I'm using JS `Audio` class to play a file:

```
var audio = new Audio('hello.mp3');
audio.play();
```

Is there a way to use an event to detect the file play has ended?

Comment: It's the same thing. Same solutions apply.

Comment: @j08691 So? Does that mean it's a duplicate? You made a mistake you should reopen. This questions does not exist in SO.

Comment: I wasn't the only one to VTC and yes, it's still a dupe

Comment: Two wrongs doesn't make it right. It's not a duplicate because the question does not exist. simple as that. Is closing a question as a duplicate valid because the answer is the same? Own up to your mistake. This question was not supposed to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var audio = new Audio('hello.mp3');
audio.play();
audio.onended = function() {
  console.log("The audio has ended");
};
```

Here is the [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp)